# Profiling parallel code Julia

Tags: parallel-processing, profiling, julia

How can we profile parallel code in julia? This question has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24411199/julia-how-to-profile-parallel-code). In fact, following the advice to call profile on each node does not work.

```
function profileSlaveTask(param)
         @profile slaveTask(param)
        return Profile.retrieve()
end
rrefs=Array(RemoteRef,length(workers()))
machines=workers()

for i=1:length(machines)
    rrefs[i]= @spawnat machines[i] slaveTask(initdamp)
end
pres= fetch(rrefs[1])
using ProfileView
ProfileView(pres[1],lidict=pres[2])
```

Using ProfileView I obtain :[image]

Answer (score 1):

Works just fine for me (julia 0.4.0-dev, Ubuntu 14.04):

```
p = addprocs(1)[1]

@everywhere function profile_svd(A)
    println("starting profile_svd")
    @profile svd(sdata(A))
    println("done with svd")
    Profile.retrieve()
end

println("about to allocate SharedArray")
A = SharedArray(Float64,1000,1000)
println("about to fill SharedArray")
rand!(sdata(A))
println("about to call worker")
bt, lidict = remotecall_fetch(p, profile_svd, A)
```